# DRY in Angular pipes

Tags: angular, dry, angular-pipe

I have a couple of amount variables which I want to format via currency pipe. This is the very simplified version of component's template:

```
<p>{{amount1 | currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0'}}</p>
...
<p>{{amount2 | currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0'}}</p>
...
<div>{{amount3 | currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0'}}</div>
...
<h1>{{amount4 | currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0'}}</h1>
```

How to achieve DRY in this example? Notice that the amount elements are not in the same level (i.e. couldn't be generated via *ngFor).

p.s. also it would be great to see the parametrized solution (in case of some currencies have another configs, like currencyCode, digitsInfo etc.)

Comment: Is using `*ngFor` an option?

Comment: nope, this  a very simplified version of template and in real example this kind of amounts are in different div-s, span-s etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the `CurrencyPipe`:

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'usdCurrency'
})
export class UsdCurrencyPipe extends CurrencyPipe {
  transform(value: number, digitsInfo: string = "1.0-0"): any {
    return super.transform(value, "USD", "symbol", digitsInfo);  }
}
```

and apply that custom pipe in your template:

```
<p>{{amount1 | usdCurrency }}</p>
<p>{{amount2 | usdCurrency }}</p>
<div>{{amount3 | usdCurrency }}</div>
<h1>{{amount4 | usdCurrency : "1.2-2" }}</h1>
```

In the example above, `digitsInfo` is available as an optional parameter. The other parameters could be made available if needed (`currencyCode`, `display`, `locale`).

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrudeb) for a demo.